# Parse Javascript Cloud Code .save() works only on a single user

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, cloud

I use Parse in iOS to run a cloud code method that gets an ID in it's request and receives a number in the response.

The purpose of the cloud code function is to take the request ID and add it to a field of 3 different users.

Here is the cloud code method in Javascript:

```
amount = 3;
// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:
Parse.Cloud.define("addToIDs", function(request, response) {

   var value = request.params.itemId;

   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
   query.ascending("createdAt");
   query.limit(100);
   query.find({
     success: function(results) {
      var sent = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var idlst = results[i].get("idString"); 
        if (idlst != null && idlst.indexOf(value) <= -1) {
          idlst += value+"|";
          results[i].set("idString", idlst);
          results[i].save();
          sent = sent+1;
        }
        if (sent >= amount) {
          break;
        }
      }
      response.success(sent);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("Test failed");
    }
  });
});
```

When running this cloud code method I get a response of '3' meaning it called .save for 3 users. The problem is that when i go back to look in the Database viewer in the parse website it actually only updated a single user (Its always the same user). No matter how many times i run this code, it will only actually update the first user..

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `save` and `saveAll` are asynchronous, so you should make sure the saving process is done.
Also note that, the user object can only be updated by the owner or request with `masterkey`.

The following code should work:

```
var amount = 3;
Parse.Cloud.define("addToIDs", function(request, response) {

    var value = request.params.itemId;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.ascending("createdAt");
    query.limit(100);
    return query.find()
        .then(function(results) { // success
            var toSave = [];
            var promise = new Parse.Promise();
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var idlst = results[i].get("idString");
                if (idlst != null && idlst.indexOf(value) <= -1) {
                    idlst += value+"|";
                    results[i].set("idString", idlst);
                    toSave.push(results[i]);
                }
                if (toSave.length >= amount) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // use saveAll to save multiple object without bursting multiple request
            Parse.Object.saveAll(toSave, {
                useMasterKey: true,
                success: function(list) {
                    promise.resolve(list.length);
                },
                error: function() {
                    promise.reject();
                }
            });
            return promise;    
        }).then(function(length) { // success
            response.success(length);
        }, function() { // error
            response.error("Test failed");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is two-fold:

1. ***save()*** is an asynchronous method, and
2. ***response.success()*** will immediately kill your running code as soon as it's called.

So what's happening is that inside your for loop you're running ***save()*** several times, but since it's asynchronous, they're simply thrown into the processing queue and your for loop continues on through. So it's quickly throwing all of your ***save()***'s into the processing queue, and then it reaches your ***response.success()*** call but, by the time it's reached, only one of the ***save()***'s has had a chance to successfully process.